# Merged git remotes not visible on single remote

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-remote

I've the following git remote configuration in order to push changes to two separate repositories (inspired by [pull/push from multiple remote locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849308/pull-push-from-multiple-remote-locations#answer-3195446)):

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git@bitbucket.org:sgrodzicki/test.git
    url = git@github.com:sgrodzicki/test.git
```

This works well until I make a new clone somewhere:

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:sgrodzicki/test.git
```

The clone configuration has only one host:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git@bitbucket.org:sgrodzicki/test.git
```

The same thing with the other repository (GitHub):

```
git clone git@github.com:sgrodzicki/test.git
```

Then it looks like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git@github.com:sgrodzicki/test.git
```

My question is: **how to make these configuration changes visible on both hosts?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration of your remotes isn't part of the information that's cloned - like many things in your git directory, it's considered private information.

You just have to do something like the following in each repository:

```
git remote set-url --add origin git@github.com:sgrodzicki/test.git
```

... after cloning.